# Does the artisan's level carry through to higher acts?

Tags: diablo-iii

Before investing a small fortune into levelling up my artisan (currently on act I) I want to know if his level carries through to the next act, otherwise I'll just wait and level him in the last act.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not only do the Artisans' levels carry through to higher acts, but they're *shared across all characters on your account*.

The one exception being that Hardcore characters have a separate set of Artisans. But as long as you stick to one "core" (either hard *or* soft), know that your Artisans will not lose levels when swapping difficulty, character, or act.

Answer (score 4):

Artisans maintain their levels (and any [learned recipes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68620/can-the-same-artisan-plan-be-used-to-make-the-same-item-n-times)) not only across acts, but also across characters (with the exception of hardcore vs normal; artisans leveled by hardcore characters are not accessible to normal characters, and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they carry through. They even carry between difficulties and characters: The artisan levels when you start a new game on nightmare will be the same as where you left it when you finished the game in the lower difficulty.