# Can the same artisan plan be used to make the same item N times?

Tags: diablo-iii

The guide states that a plan can be used for the artisan to "learn" to craft a specific item, so I'm assuming that this knowledge can be used to make that item as much times as I want, is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes.

The Plan is expended once it is "taught", but then you can make as many as you can afford.